# How to check if the author of a message was a Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I know this question has been asked before but it's 2020 now not 2018, so how do you check if the author of a message was a bot?

Comment: Same way regardless of year, you would of known if you tried before asking

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Okay I asked this question because my friend didn't know and I showed my friend the answer that I accepted and it didn't work also I did google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discordjs documentation, you can check if a author of a message is a bot by using `message.author.bot`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot

This is a boolean value.